# Show that the set $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus A$ is simply-connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

The set $A$ is defined by $A =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}, |x| \ge 1 \} \cup \{ iy : y \in \mathbb{R}, |y| \ge 1 \}$. For the problem, we use the following definition of simply-connected:

Definition: A connected open subset $\Omega$ of the complex plane is simply-connected if $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \phi^{−1}(\Omega)$ is connected, where $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the 2-sphere and $\phi:\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{p\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is stereographic projection.

Note that it is enough to check that $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \phi^{−1}(A)$ is arc-connected.

But I do not know how to prove that $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \phi^{−1}(A)$ is arc-connected.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is $\phi$? It is also not really clear what $\mathbb{S}_2$ is, seeing as that is usually the surface of the three-dimensional sphere.

Comment: is the  stereographic projection

Comment: I don't think you need stereographic projection for this problem: every point in $\Bbb C\setminus A$ can be connected to $0$ by a straight line. (Indeed, this space is contractible, hence simply connected.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = S^2 - \phi(A)$ and let $p$ denote the projection point (e.g., the north pole of the sphere.) To show that $X$ is arc-connected, pick two points $x, y$ in $X$ different from $p$. Let $x' = \phi(x)$ and $y' = \phi(y)$ denote the projected images of $x$ and $y$.  Now, $x'$ can be connected to the origin in $\mathbb{C}$ by a straight-line path (specifically, by the path $t \mapsto (1 - t)x'$). The same is true, of course, about $y$. By means of concatenation, this yields a path from $x'$ to $y'$ that consists of two line segments joined at the origin. Applying $\phi^{-1}$ to this path produces a path in $X$ that connects $x$ to $y$.

What if one of the points in $X$, say the point $y$, happens to be the projection point? (i.e., what if $y = p$?) If $x$ is not antipodal to $p$ (i.e., if $x \ne -p$) then we can connect $x$ to $p$ by using a segment of the unique great circle that passes through $x$ and $p$. You can easily verify that this path is in $X$ by projecting it with $\phi$ and observing that the image doesn't intersect $A$. And if $x = -p$, then we can similarly connect $-p$ to $p$ along a great circle path, provided we pick a great circle through $-p$ and $p$ that avoids $\phi^{-1}(A)$ (we do have to make a choice here, but every great circle except two particular ones will work!)